# Is composition less performant than inheritance in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, performance, inheritance, composition

I come from an OOP background and I've mostly worked with inheritance. In JavaScript inheritance is easy to figure out, but here's how I've tried using composition, basically following [this guide](https://alligator.io/js/class-composition/).

```js
const canSayHi = self => ({
  sayHi: () => console.log(`Hi! I'm ${self.name}`)
});

const alligatorBehaviors = self => ({
  bite: () => console.log("Yum yum!")
});


const alligator = name => {
  const self = {
    name
  };

  return Object.assign(self, canSayHi(self), alligatorBehaviors(self));
};


const jack = alligator("jack");
jack.sayHi(); // Hi! I'm jack
jack.bite(); // Yum yum!
```

This and all other approaches like that all have the same issue - the behaviour functions return new functions, which means that every instance of the composed object is going to have all of its "methods" uniquely built for it and taking up memory.

If I understand correctly, when using classes and building object methods using the object prototype object, the methods are only created once on the prototype and then called by reference each time an instantiated object needs them.

So - a prototype object only creates functions on class definition and then you can instantiate it a 1000 times and there will still only be 1 instance of the class and each of its methods in memory. In the case of composition, however, each of those 1000 objects would have their own function implementations in memory taking up a lot more memory.

The thing that I'm not so sure about is if this performance hit is negligible or not. Considering that JavaScript is often run on bad/old devices and that there might be use cases that require thousands of instantiated objects, it seems to me that this performance hit is something that needs to be taken into account.

Comment: I think this question is as old as javascript, there are many [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+inheritance+vs+instance+methods) already.

Comment: The real question for any approach one is  going to choose is ... *Is one going to create a type/object system with thousands of instances with each one enclosing its state locally or carrying it openly/publicly?* This single feature has the by far biggest impact on everything, design/approach, memory consumption, performance in accessing/looking up properties (even though I would not anymore worry too much about memory and performance).

Comment: @RobG I tried looking for some existing topics, but none of the ones I could find focused on the performance aspect. I'll take a look at the link you provided. Edit: None of the top-most questions with that query covered the performance aspect from what I could tell.

Comment: @PeterSeliger can you elaborate please? Could you provide examples for both approaches and explain why this aspect is the one with the biggest impact?

Comment: @Fabis ... I will, later in the evening. But there is something you already now might consider. The provided example code demonstrates a composition approach based on objects and closures. Thus any object created by the `alligator` factory does not carry any single (state) property, only its methods are public. Try to do this with prototypal delegation (hence inheritance) and without the syntax of private instance fields and private instance methods. How would an implementation look like?

Comment: This is not (object) composition. It's *parasitic inheritance* or *mixins*. The author of that article did not understand what "composition over inheritance" means.

Comment: @Bergi What's the correct way to represent composition in JavaScript? What's the correct way to represent it without using classes & interfaces (in TypeScript)? Don't these correct approaches, whatever they may be, still have the same performance issue?

Comment: @Bergi ... 1/2 ... before I'm going to answer *Fabis* wrongly, I need an update on terminology. Purely technically seen *inheritance*, in my opinion, comes with some *system automatism(s)*. Any other *reusable code*, especially in JavaScript, which *__explicitly__ assigns/applies methods/behavior to objects* (regardless of the chosen technique / school / teaching), and therefore does not aggregate, already qualifies for whatever kind of *mixin based composition*.

Comment: @Bergi ... 2/2 ...  And I strongly oppose the term *parasitic inheritance* where inheritance does not take place (no system automatism). The technique used by the OP glues methods to an object and does so by creating closures in order to additionally provide (inject) state (in)to a local (thus *"private"*) scope (here per behavior). A correct term from a pure JS perspective would by "stateful, privileged behavior" or "stateful privileged mixin". So where am I wrong with this perspective?

Comment: @Fabis ... regarding your introduction *"I come from an OOP background and I've mostly worked with inheritance."*. What you did present and what gets discussed right now is as purely ***OO*** as can be ... 1) objects and 2) functions as 2a) methods, as 2b) factories and as 2c) closures. Thats already a reliable base for creating complex object/type systems. ***OO*** does neither depend on *inheritance* nor does *inheritance* depend on a class concept. But of cause the latter makes the programmers live much easier.

Comment: @PeterSeliger—regarding your comments on parasitic inheritance, you might like to read Douglas Crockford's [*Classical Inheritance in JavaScript*](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html), which covers what he calls classical, multiple and parasitic inheritance. Unfortunately it's not dated, but it's likely about 10 years old.

Comment: @RobG ... I know Doug Crockford and all of his contributions from the beginning. He was/is kind of a *"spirituell"* teacher to everyone who was going deep into JavaScript from even the times before ... *"JavaScript: The Wrrrld's Most Misunderstood Programming Language"*. And *Fabis'* example does not have the slightest in common with Crockford's *parasitic inheritance* introduced back then with this author's (now accumulated) inheritance articles.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Ah, you're right, there's no parasitic inheritance taking place here - we only have a single "class" `alligator`, the other functions are mixins that take an object to amend, instead of creating it on their own. The approaches are similar and use the same techniques (and fit well together) so I was confused.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I think your term "*mixin based composition*" is perfectly fine, and I'm looking for your answer :-) All I wanted to clarify in my comment was that "[composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)" refers to [nesting objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition), not other kinds of composition.

Comment: @Fabis ... please have a look at the *jsbench* test of ... [*mixin vs class based and local vs public state*](https://jsbench.me/0mkn7wwj7n/1)

Comment: @PeterSeliger Class based inheritance & prototype mixin tests were the fastest which is what I assumed, as described in my OP. So that's the answer?